# Enable/disable a admin configuration of a module based on other configuration of other module

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Is it possible to have a configuration with a source model`(adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno)` that depends on another configuration in a different module?

Example:

Enabling or disabling module A depends on whether module B is enabled.I tried the `<depends>...</depends>` but it works for same module configurations only :(

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can make your own source model to achieve this.

Anyway, why don't you just check if module B is enabled when testing the same thing for module A ? So your condition would be induced by your code, and not by some system config fields that would not be really safe regarding what you want to do (you could enable module A when module B is also enabled, but then what would happen if module B gets disabled later ?)